# How to allow allow more than one download at the same time

Tags: python, apache, nginx, download, restriction

I'm developing an application that will send files to an user, but I need to send more than one at the same time and what is happening is that when he is downloading the first one, the page still loading until the first one has finished so then it starts...
Wha I'd like to know what can I do to send more than one at the same time. Is that some sort of nginx/apache configuration? Does anyone has some tip for me study or something like that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway you could have the file delivery system use threads? 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Any threading documentation will be better that what I will be able to explain, but essentially you'll have

```
class MyMainThing(object):
    def __init__(things):
         #everything in your site
    def user_clicked_download(self):
         threading.Thread(target=download_file(arg),).start() # threading takes tuple arg

def download_file(arg):
    # your downloading stuff.
```

Sorry for the vague example, if you include code I might be able to explain better, but you asked for something you can research, and threading seems like it would definitely help you out here. Also, it's basically mandatory if you want to do multiple things at once.

Let me know if you need a better explanation or have any questions. I'll answer as best I can!

Comment: hello ford, maybe this works... I've done some research and found out that apache put the processes into a queue when come from the same IP and requesting the same thing... do you know if it will happen even with threads?